# Appearance proxies / UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR in Swift?

Tags: swift, uikit, uiappearance

The Apple documentation states:

> To participate in the appearance proxy API, tag your appearance
>   property selectors in your header with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR.

In Objective-C one can annotate properties with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *foregroundColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

**How can I do the same in Swift?**

Answer (score 51):

Mark your custom view property as `dynamic`.

For example:

```
class YourCustomView: UIView {
    @objc dynamic var subviewColor: UIColor? {
        get { return self.yourSubview.backgroundColor }
        set { self.yourSubview.backgroundColor = newValue }
    }
    ...
}
```

Then:

```
YourCustomView.appearance().subviewColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Comment: I need to try that out. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not documented, but I tried and it worked. Basically Swift properties dynamically accessed from Objective-C frameworks should be marked as dynamic. UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR is just a compiler annotation for code completion, and it has no effect on runtime. Check /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer‌​/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAppeara‌​nce.h

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with UIBarButton subclass in Xcode 8.3.2 iOS 9.1 and makes crash of UIKit after I set appearance and instantiate new Custom UIBarButtonSubclass

Comment: Also need to add the `@objc` attribute to the property to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

I did not find the solution but a workaround.
Instead of annotating the properties I made them as a class variable.

```
private struct StarFillColor { static var _color = UIColor.blackColor() }
internal class var starFillColor: UIColor {
    get { return StarFillColor._color }
    set { StarFillColor._color = newValue }
}
```

And in the file where I setup all my appearances:

```
MyClass.starFillColor = UIColor.r(181, g: 60, b: 109)
```

I hope it will help somebody!

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, you don't need (actually, you cannot) to annotate properties with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`.

Just make sure your appearance property accessor methods be of the form:

> ```
> func propertyForAxis1(axis1: IntegerType, axis2: IntegerType, axisN: IntegerType) -> PropertyType
> func setProperty(property: PropertyType, forAxis1 axis1: IntegerType, axis2: IntegerType)
> ```
>
> *Source: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearancecontainer)*

For example:

```
func setStarViewColor(color: UIColor) {
    self.backgroundColor = color
}
```

Then you can set your appearance property like this:

```
MyView.appearance().setStarViewColor(someColor)
```

I currently using this solution in my Swift project and it works, hope it's helpful to you too.

Comment: Hi, can you post your class you're using it in please! I can't seem to call my setter correctly, I get a `BAD_ACCESS` when try to call it. I'm wondering if I'm declaring my class correctly, its a sub class of `UIButton` and I'm conforming to `UIAppearanceContainer` like it says in the docs! Cheers!

Comment: @Rich Checkout my [gist](https://gist.github.com/guojiubo/adff619fdba8f8ba698c), including the whole class, hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't allow me to change the color for specific instance. Any idea how this can  be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: Sadly a very late response to this, but I found that marking the methods as dynamic resolved the BAD_ACCESS issue for UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

Based on previous answers, here is the extension to UIView I implemented to manage UIView appearance with view borders, I hope it can help someone :

```
extension UIView {
    @objc dynamic  var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = self.layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set(color) {
            self.layer.borderColor = color?.cgColor
        }
    }

    @objc dynamic  var borderWidth: NSNumber? {
        get { return NSNumber(value: Float(self.layer.borderWidth))}
        set(width) {
            self.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(width?.floatValue ?? 0)
        }
    }

    @objc dynamic  var cornerRadius: NSNumber? {
        get { return NSNumber(value: Float(self.layer.cornerRadius))}
        set(radius) {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(radius?.floatValue ?? 0)
        }
    }
}
```